# Best way to access entry data from within Playa field?

Tags: playa, stash, parse-order

I have a channel `items` and a channel `colors`, and the `items` channel has a Playa field `item_colors` that links to the `colors` channel. What is the best way to loop through the `items` entries and output a construct like this?

{

```
  "color_1" : "item_1",
  "color_2" : "item_1",
  "color_3" : "item_1",

  "color_1" : "item_2",
  "color_4" : "item_2",

  "color_5" : "item_3",

  "color_2" : "item_4",
  "color_3" : "item_4",

}
```

The tricky part is outputting the outer entry title from within the Playa field tag pair. I attempted to do this with a Stash variable:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="items" dynamic="no" disable="categories|member_data|pagination"}
  {exp:stash:item_title}{title}{/exp:stash:item_title}
  {item_colors}
    "{title}": "{stash:item_title}",
  {/item_colors}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

But the result is the Stash variable outputs the same (last) entry title for every instance. Something about parse order, undoubtedly… any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good news, it should be a quick fix. All you need is to prefix your Playa variables with [var_prefix](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/playa/templating/module/children.html) parameter to differentiate the namespace from the Channel Entry variables, although you might have to use the full module tag:

```
{exp:playa:children field="item_colors" var_prefix="pl"}
    "{pl:title}": "{title}",
{/exp:playa:children}
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I needed. Now I don't have to also agonize over why I was apparently able to output the stash variable only once... EE really drives me nuts sometimes!